# How to Map MongoDB Bson Dosument in F# to generic type

Tags: mongodb, f#

I am new to F# - I have a converter for Bson to a model

```
module BsonDocConverter 
  open MongoDB.Bson
  open Models

  let toDraw (bdoc: BsonDocument) : Draw = 
        {
          drawDate = bdoc.["drawDate"].AsBsonDateTime.ToLocalTime()
          number1 = bdoc.["number1"].AsInt32
          number2 = bdoc.["number2"].AsInt32
          number3 = bdoc.["number3"].AsInt32
          number4 = bdoc.["number4"].AsInt32
          number5 = bdoc.["number5"].AsInt32
          number6 = bdoc.["number6"].AsInt32
        }
```

Then in other code, I retrieve the son document from the database ( Just find all )

```
let getDraws: seq<Models.Draw> = 
    let db = MongoClient().GetDatabase("numbers")
    let draws :System.Collections.Generic.List<BsonDocument> = db.GetCollection("draws").Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.op_Implicit(sprintf "{}")).ToList()
    let newDraws = draws |> Seq.map BsonDocConverter.toDraw 
    newDraws
```

Is this the right way to do this?  I am used to C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in a way that's much more idiomatic to F#, so you're working directly with your model types rather than BSON documents. Something like this:

```
open System
open MongoDB.Bson
open MongoDB.Driver

type Draw =
    {
        id : BsonObjectId
        drawDate : DateTime
        number1 : int
        number2 : int
        number3 : int
        number4 : int
        number5 : int
        number6 : int
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let dbClient = MongoClient("mongodb://your.server.com")
    let db = dbClient.GetDatabase("yourdata")
    let coll = db.GetCollection<Draw>("draws")
    let draw = coll.Find(fun d -> d.number1 = 1234).FirstOrDefault()
    printfn "%A" draw
    0
```

This will let you get rid of the `toDraw` function entirely.

There are a few guides available if you search around. Here's one: [link](https://medium.com/@mukund.sharma92/cruding-in-f-with-mongodb-e4699d1ac17e).

Comment: Thanks - but what drivers are you using for that? Can you change to the full code? the link you posted is using a driver that has not been updated for 7-8 years and I couldn't get it working with that.

Comment: I'm just using the normal MongoDB.Driver. I'll update my answer to include full code. It compiles successfully, but I can't test it because I don't have your data.

Comment: Thanks.  Assuming you have a column in your Model called _id ( standard field )  - how to I put that in my type so it serialises it properly?  It complains if I don't have the _id member - and if I put it in as a string I get FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'String' from BsonType

Comment: Oops, yes, I deleted that by accident. Your ID field should be of type `BsonObjectId`. I'll update the full code accordingly.